# Best way to chunk a large string by line

Tags: python, regex, string, file, split

I have a large file (400+ MB) that I'm reading in from S3 using `get_contents_as_string()`, which means that I end up with the entire file in memory as a string. I'm running several other memory-intensive operations in parallel, so I need a memory-efficient way of splitting the resulting string into chunks by line number. Is `split()` efficient enough? Or is something like `re.finditer()` a better way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see three options here, from the most memory-consuming to the least:

1. `split` will create a copy of your file as a list of strings, meaning additional 400 MB used. Easy to implement, takes RAM.
2. Use `re` or simply iterate over a string and memorize `\n` positions: `for i, c in enumerate(s): if c == '\n': newlines.append(i+1)`.
3. The same as point 2, but with the string stored as a file on HDD. Slow but really memory efficient, also addressing the disadvantage of Python strings - they're immutable, and if one wants to do some changes, interpreter will create a copy. Files don't suffer from this, allowing in-place operations without loading the whole file at all.

I would also suggest to encapsulate solutions 2 or 3 into a separate class in order to keep newline indexes and the string contents consistent. `Proxy` pattern and the idea of `lazy evaluation` would fit here, I think.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to read the file line by line

```
f= open(filename)

partialstring = f.readline()
```

see
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: My data is in a string, not a file, so that will not work.